# Create batch file that add files to array with certain string of characters in filename

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will grab specific files from a directory that have a specific prefix. I am then trying to add those files to an array.

For example, if I had `123456789`, `123456987`, `123456123`, `123456958`, `366554788`, I want to be able to put those in a string if they contained `123456` as the first six characters in the filename.

As a result, you'd have:

```
123456789
123456987
123456123
123456958
```

I have searched through some documentation, but I can't find where I could grab files with certain characters in the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this pseudo-code to give you some idea :

```bat
@echo off
Set "MyFolder=C:\temp\Test\"
Set "Pattern=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Count=0

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir "%MyFolder%" /a-d /b ^|findstr /R "%Pattern%"') do (
    Set "FileName=%%~na"
    Set "Prefix=!FileName:~0,6!"
    If [!Prefix!]==[123456] (
        Set /a Count+=1
        Set "File[!count!]=%%a"     
    )

)

For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    echo !File[%%i]!
)
pause
```